# WebViews UID same as the apps UID?

Tags: android, webview, android-webview

Does someone know, if I launch android web-view window from my app, would it have the same UID as the app that lunched it. I am using Samsung phones, I think they use the Web-Kit browser, but I would also want to know for phones that use chrome.

I tried testing it, but I don't know if the traffic which was generated in built in web browser comes only from it or it includes traffic from the web view that I launched from my app.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

WebView runs as a part of your application. Thus, if your app has an activity that uses WebView, and you load some URL in this WebView, all this will happen under your app's UID.

However, if your app launches an intent to view a URL, it will be handled by the browser app (Samsung browser or Chrome, for example), and that will run under its own UID.